# why the pairs in table is different by different init ways

Tags: lua

in the 2 example, the table seems do the same things.but the output is different.

```
local a = {
    [0] = 0,
    [1] = 1,
    [2] = 2,
    [3] = 3,

}
for i, v in pairs(a) do
    print(v)
end
```

the output is
0
2
3
1

```
local a = {}
a[0] = 0
a[1] = 1
a[2] = 2
a[3] = 3

for i, v in pairs(a) do
    print(v)
end
```

the output is 1 2 3 0

**it seems like the second example is always output array part first then hash part.
but the first example seems like the order is random.
why?**

Answer (score 3):

`pairs` doesn't guarantee a specific order. If you want to have a specific order use a numeric for loop.

```
for i = 0, 3 do
  print(a[i])
end
```

Read

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pairs

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-next

> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even
> for numeric indices. (To traverse a table in numerical order, use a
> numerical for.)

Answer (score 1):

Not only does `pairs` not guarantee a specific order, table constructors furthermore don't guarantee a specific order of insertion:

> The order of the assignments in a constructor is undefined. (This order would be relevant only when there are repeated keys.)

- [the Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.9)

Therefore, this claim:

> the table seems do the same things

is wrong. It might as well be equivalent to:

```lua
local a = {}
a[3] = 3
a[2] = 2
a[1] = 1
a[0] = 0

for i, v in pairs(a) do
    print(v)
end
```

So even if table traversal order is deterministically determined by the insertions - same insertions, same traversal - which wouldb an **implementation detail** - table constructors may not be read from left to right, line by line - as Lua may shuffle the assignments however it likes.

Furthermore, hashmaps will in practice have to *resize* and *resolve collisions*. Lua will be able to avoid at least the resize if you use a table constructor expression; it might theoretically even minimize the effort required to resolve collisions by picking an intelligent insertion order.